# Are romantic tattoos bad luck in D&D?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, greyhawk, romance

I'm currently running a 3.5e campaign set in Greyhawk and one of my players, a half-orc fighter, has begun a romantic relationship with one of the NPC's.

During some down time, she decided to visit a tattoo shop and get a tattoo of her and the NPC's initials.

After getting the tattoo she's worried it might be bad luck for the relationship, similar to what people believe in real life.

I couldn't find any lore about this in any of the d&d realms. Has anyone read anything about this, or will it just be up to DM discretion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tattoos are reasonably common in Greyhawk.  Their usage varies from culture to culture.  They are mostly found as symbols of religious devotion (public or secret - tattoos of Wee Jas, Nerull, etc. are used to identify other cultists), but they are also found as "recreational use" - here's the description of a Greyhawk City Marine captain...

> His forearms look like hams, and are covered in tattoos
>   of females in various stages of undress together
>   with brief expressions of undying love for
>   each of them. He is always accompanied by his
>   savage parrot Albrecht.       - *From the Ashes p.86*

The Rovers of the Barrens are heavily tattooed, as are the Olman.

There's not a lot of detail on "civilized" use of this sort - romantic tattoos, tramp stamps, etc. - so that'd be up to you and your players to make up as you go!

Answer (score 15):

There is no lore about this in D&D. (Granted that proving a negative is impossible, I will confidently make that claim, to my knowledge.) In general, lore from the D&D rules themselves is limited to spells, monsters, races, and classes, and everything else is left more-or-less undefined, so that it can be up to the designer of a particular campaign world or setting.

As for the setting of Greyhawk, again no, to my knowledge there is no existing lore on such a superstition either.

If you're not playing in a particular world, or if the particular world you're playing in doesn't say either way on a detail like the superstitions around tattoos, these details are always up to you, the DM — because you're the setting's designer or co-designer in that case.

Comment: The querent has specified Greyhawk.